# Executing php code from an html file using ajax

Tags: php

I am new to php development and I am stuck on something stupid : I want to execute a php script from my html page.

I do the following to do so :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "test1.php",
        success: function(response) {
            //alert(response);
            console.log(response);
        },

        error: function(response) {

        }
    });
```

But when I log the response, I see the php source code in the response :

```
[Log] <?php  (localhost, line 23)
  $output = "LALALALALALALALALALALALALA"
  echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Can you load test1.php in your browser and check if you see LALALALALA or similar to the log response?

Comment: I found the problem (I didn't describe the problem well enough, I'll make an edit), I didn't configure well my nginx server so it wasn't using the php interpreter. Now I am running on a 502 error, but I made one step forward ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
call in head tag

```
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

in javascript tag

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test1.php",
                success: function (html) {
console.log(response);
                },

        error: function(response) {

        }
            });
        return false;
```

Comment: check the response from developer tool in chrom